# How to render PDF using poppler in pyqt4 or wxpython?

Tags: python, pdf, wxpython, poppler

My goal is to create a pdf viewer that can select a text in the viewer.

is it possible? 
i'm only experienced using wxpython for deleveloping gui application. I just heard poppler can support rendering pdf, but i did not found any snippet or example. please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732178/extracting-text-from-pdf-with-poppler-c answered here in a simar manner

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to create a wxPython PDF viewer, I've found a couple of examples. The first one uses Poppler as you mentioned in conjunction with wxPython:

- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577195-wxpython-pdf-viewer-using-poppler/

It's a pretty old example, so I don't know how well it works now. The other one I found uses PyMuPDF and fitz and was published this year (2016):

- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580621-wxpython-pdf-viewer-using-pymupdf-binding-for-fitz/

If you happen to be on Windows, wxPython comes with an ActiveX wrapper around Adobe's reader. You can read more about it here:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.pdfviewer.viewer.pdfViewer.html

Comment: The one that wraps Adobe's ActiveX control is in `wx.lib.pdfwin`.  The viewer in the `wx.lib.pdfviewer` package is a cross-platform solution that renders the PDF using wx and supports a commonly used subset of PDF operations so far.  It is under active development, however all the recent work has been put into the Phoenix version.

Comment: Oops. My bad. I was only aware of the Windows-only widget